# Change text-color when double clicked

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having an issue with figuring out how to change the default color on the normal text when its selected/clicked.

I can not remember what its called and I can't find it when I inspect the the code.

I am working on a WordPress child theme version of Zerif Lite.

I have included a picture of how it looks when clicked and that is also what I would like to change.

[image]

I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: `::selection` selector?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Do you want to highlight the selected text in a specified color?

Comment: Yes, the website colours for my website are blue, so it just seems off to have it be pink.

Comment: So you can search the wordpress files for `::selection` and change them OR add a `::selection { background-color:whatever !important }`to your page

Comment: The ::selection fixed it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS to highlight the selected text.

```
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
color: white;
background: #ffc0cbfa; //Pink color
```

}

```
::selection {
color: white;
background: #ffc0cbfa; //pink color
```

}